# Mailto and Hyperlink exceeding 256 characters

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel 2010

I am trying to create a hyperlink that includes a mailto to create emails with hardly any need to type things in.

Currently I am using the following formula:

> =HYPERLINK("mailto:"&C25&"&cc="&C26&"?subject="&C16&"&body="&C2,"SendEmail")

The problem is that once everything gets evaluated the hyperlink function exceeds 256 characters.

I found the following code. How can I implement this as a solution to my problem?

```
Sub insertVeryLongHyperlink()

    Dim curCell As Range
    Dim longHyperlink As String

    Set curCell = Range("C31")   ' or use any cell-reference
    longHyperlink = Range("C30")  ' Or a Cell reference like [C1]

    curCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=curCell, _
                    Address:=longHyperlink, _
                    SubAddress:="", _
                    ScreenTip:=" - Click here to follow the hyperlink", _
                    TextToDisplay:="Long Hyperlink"

End Sub
```

Update:

I tried `longHyperlink = Range("C30")`

Where C30 has the following, including the ":

> "mailto:"&C25&"&cc="&C26&"?subject="&C16&"&body="&C2,"SendEmail"

When I trying to execute the link created it gives me a Microsoft Warning about would I like to open this file.

When I say yes it gives me an unexpected error has occurred.

Comment: Does C30 contain the information from all of C25, C26, C16, and C2 used in the old formula?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 C30 contains what I had In my hyperlink 

But I get an error. 

I'm trying to recreate what I had In my hyperlink but without the 256 character limit

Comment: right now, you're setting `longHyperlink` to just be the text `"C30"`. You actually want it to be the value of the range C30, like this `longHyperlink=Range("C30").Value`

Comment: can we see what's in C30 after you added the vba code?

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 that's a good suggestion. Unfortunately I'm nz based  so not at work and don't have access to it yet. I will try it tomorrow and update you

Comment: @SNicolaou my C30 just includes what's in my hyperlink so the following ```mailto:"&C25&"&cc="&C26&"?subject="&C16&"&body="&C2,"SendEmail```

Comment: I am a bit concerned about those commas you have in there, can’t test now, fire drill in my office building

Comment: can you put the '?' right after the recipient and before the 'cc'.

Comment: @SNicolaou hi I don't have access to my files just now. I'm off work (nz based 8.30pm here) will try it 1st thing get in and let you know.

Comment: Any progress? If you change something about your attempt, make sure you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58741224/edit) it in so we can further troubleshoot with you!

Comment: Just updated and edited

Comment: C30 should not still have the text `", SendEmail"` in it. That is only necessary for the `HYPERLINK()` formula

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I see what you mean. But I do need to send the contents in the cells as email. Is there a work around?